# Quartz plugin with Multitenant -single tenant mode

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, multi-tenant

I am using both multi-tenant-core1.0.3(Single tenant mode) and quartz 0.4.2 plugins in my project. I have created the scheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean) bean in the resources.groovy.

```
beans = {
        quartzScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean) {
                autoStartup = false
                dataSource = ref('dataSource')
                transactionManager = ref('transactionManager')
                configLocation = 'classpath:quartz.properties'
                jobFactory = ref('quartzJobFactory')
                jobListeners = [ref("${SessionBinderJobListener.NAME}")]
                globalJobListeners = [ref("${ExceptionPrinterJobListener.NAME}")]
        }
}
```

When I create a job from my default tenant, the job is created and executed on the scheduled time. When I create the job from other tenants, it inserts records in the respective tenant's db tables qrtz_triggers, qrtz_simple_triggers and qrtz_job_details. But the job is not executing. I think the job executor is still looking into the main db.

Can any one tell me, what should be configured or any work around to resolve this issue?

Comment: In the scheduler, we can  always set one tenant context than having tenant based contexts.